# Up Navigation doubts

Tags: android

I implemented in my application, in a screen showing the information "Up Navigation". It worked, however when I click on the icon with the arrow on the ActionBar, it's not a return effect, like that when I click on the return arrow Smarthphone itself but rather an effect as if I had started a new Activity. I wonder if someone could help me with this doubt.

My Code:

```
  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
          case android.R.id.home:
              // é aqui que você volta para a activity ou fragment anterior
              Intent parentActivityIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
              // Remove todas as outras activitys que estão na pilha
              parentActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
              startActivity(parentActivityIntent);
              finish();
              break;

      }
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
```

Comment: How did you implement it? Typically for "up" navigation, you need to specify the parent activity in the manifest.

Comment: My doubt is not to implement. It is when I click on the Up Navigation, back to the previous Activity as if he had started a new one. I wonder how the the effect of Fade in when you return

Comment: The system will handle the transition differently, depending on how you implement. Please edit your question to include the code showing how you have implemented up.

Comment: Ready! I edited the code

Answer (score 0):

This button's action can be implemented in the

```
 onOptionItemSelected()
```

You can find its id as android.R.id.home

the action you can take as

```
       if(item.getItemId()==android.R.id.home)
     {
          //Your action
      }
```

Comment: OP has implemented up, probably this way. It's the `// your action` bit that OP has trouble with if programmatically setting action.

Comment: OK, May be I was unable to understand this.

Answer (score 0):

You're starting a new intent, in a new task, which is why the system animation is different than when pressing back.

You have already setup the home button correctly, as you receive the `android.R.id.home` event in `onOptionsItemSelected` when you press the up button.

You should add the `android:parentActivityName` attribute in your manifest (API 16+ see developer docs link below for backwards compatibility).

This associates your current activity with a parent. You also need the correct onClick action using the [NavUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NavUtils.html) class to `navigateUpFromSameTask(this)` where `this` is your current Activity.

The [developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) is clear on how to correctly implement up; the return transition effect will be given for free if following the prescribed patterns.

---

As an aside, in your code, you should `return true` instead of `break` (which will do nothing because you aren't in a loop). Returning `true` means that you have handled the event, `onOptionsItemSelected`.

Comment: How could I implement to get the return effect?